# Finding if elements of a vector of vector is present in another vector

Tags: c++, vector

How would I see if the elements in column of vectors or vectors (ruleList) are present in another vector called ntList (not a vector of vectors). I currently have:

```
for(int j = 0; j < ruleList[0].size(); j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ntList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(std::find(ruleList[0][j].begin(), ruleList[0][j].end(), ntList[i]) != ruleList[0][j].end())
        {   
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            errorList.push_back(ERROR1);
            error = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error, but I'm not entirely sure why.

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
```

Any help would be appreciated. Declarations of vectors:

```
vector<string> ntList;
vector< vector<string> > ruleList(100, vector<string> (0, "0"));
```

Comment: "I'm getting an error" right now we're not. *Post the full error*.

Comment: error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion). If I change ntList[i] to ntList[i][0] above, it compiles just fine, but doesn't give the output I want.

Comment: Also post the full declarations of the `ruleList` and `ntList` variables. And please update *the question*, don't just plop them in a comment.

Comment: @user3326306 either your errors are really sparse, or that wasn't the full error.  The compiler doesn't spew text at you for no reason, the error text has meaning!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, [std::equal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/) or (C++11 only) [std::is_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_permutation/) may be sufficient. Those algorithms are good enough if you just want to check if the vectors have exactly the same values stored in them and have the same size.

If you want to do more, e.g. storing the missing values somewhere else, then you may be better off with a hand-written loop. Assuming you are dealing with std::vector in both cases and are not using C++11:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter_rule_list = ruleList[0].begin(); iter_rule_list != ruleList[0].end(); ++iter_rule_list)
{
    int const value = *iter_rule_list;
    if (std::find(ntList.begin(), ntList.end(), value) == ntList.end())
    {
        // value missing in ntList
    }
}
```